# Show all changes to all files in all commits since a specified one

Tags: git

How do you get git to show all changes made to all files in all commits, since a specified commit (that might've been a few hundred commits ago)?

I can find how to show all changes to one file, or all changes in one commit, or a list of changed files, but I have not found any documentation on how to show the full diffs for all changes across an entire repository, in the order that they were made, since an arbitrary point in history. (I understand that the volume of output will be large.)

Comment: "*How do you get git to show all changes made to all files in all commits, **since** a specified commit (that might've been a few hundred commits ago)?*" Short answer is to use [`git log --since`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---sinceltdategt). Did you try it already and rejected for some reason?

Comment: How about `git log -p`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***tl;dr***: You probably want `git log -p --since=<date of the commit>`.

---

`git log -p` will show all the changes in each commit. See [Commit Formatting](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_formatting) for full control over what is returned for each commit.

> ...since a specified commit

That's a little more complicated because Git history is not linear (use `git log --graph` to see the true history).

If you want all commits since *by time*, find the date of the commit and use `--since`.

If you want all commits since *topologically* pass `git log` a revision range. See [Specifying Ranges](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_ranges) for details, but usually `git log <commit>..` is what you want.

See [Commit Limiting](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_limiting) for options to control which commits are shown.

> ...in the order that they were made

Reverse chronological order is the default for `git log`. See [Commit Ordering](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_ordering) for other possibilities.

For example...

```
time ---->

A - B - C - D - E - F [branch1]
         \
          I - J - K - L - M [branch2]
```

All the commits since D in time and in reverse chronological order is J - E - K - F - L - M.

All the commits since D topologically is E - F.

Up to you which one you want.